# Draw lines across a multirow in a tabular

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I am creating a question type for an exam in which three terms have to be assigned by connecting them with a line. This is to be drawn through the `multirow` of the table. The anchor points should always be in the middle at the respective edge of the cell. Depending on the question, individual cells can also be multi-row. For the sample solution of the exam I would like to connect this via latex. Can someone help me how to draw lines across the `multirow`s?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright}p{3cm}|>{\raggedright}p{2cm}|>{\raggedright}p{3cm}|>{\raggedright}p{2cm}|>{\raggedright}p{3cm}|}
\hline 
Word bla blab bla bla bla bla bla & \multirow{3}{2cm}{} & WYSIWYM & \multirow{3}{2cm}{} & .lyx\\
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5} 
\LaTeX &  & WYSIWYG &  & .docx bla bla bla bla bla bla bla\\
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5} 
Lyx &  & WYSIWYAF &  & .tex\\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. That environment is similar to the classical environment `{tabular}` (of `array`) but creates also PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells, rows and columns. You can use these nodes to draw with Tikz whatever rule you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{p[l]{3cm}p[l]{2cm}p[l]{3cm}p[l]{2cm}p[l]{3cm}}[hvlines]
Word bla blab bla bla bla bla bla & \Block{3-1}{} & WYSIWYM & \Block{3-1}{} & .lyx\\
\LaTeX &  & WYSIWYG &  & .docx bla bla bla bla bla bla bla\\
Lyx &  & WYSIWYAF &  & .tex\\
\CodeAfter 
  \tikz 
    \draw [red] (1.5-|2) -- (2.5-|3) 
                (2.5-|2) -- (3.5-|3) 
                (3.5-|2) -- (1.5-|3) 
                (1.5-|4) -- (1.5-|5) 
                (2.5-|4) -- (2.5-|5) 
                (3.5-|4) -- (3.5-|5) ;
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because of the PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]